# How to compare attributes from tables that are 3 relationships apart in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to produce some sample SQL for a database to be created with an ERD that I have already made.
The required query is https://i.stack.imgur.com/U640d.jpg
and the ERD being used is https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM5Ei.jpg

I've assumed that I need to select from the 3 tables (Message, Chat, UserChat) but I don't understand how the query would be able to match up each instance of messages and users. I've tried to make somewhat of a starting point below but can't see what else would be required.

```
SELECT MessageID, ChatID, IsText, MessageText, FileName, MessageFile
FROM tbl_Message, tbl_Chat, tbl_UserChat
WHERE tbl_Message.DateSent > UserChat.LastOpened
AND tbl_User.UserID = ‘1044’
AND tbl_Chat.ChatID = ‘139’
```

Comment: Do you actually know what `FK` and `PK` on your ERD are?

Comment: I understand that they are primary and foreign keys, yes. Just not how I would use those within the SQL statement

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`/`ON`.

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is a field or set of fields which are unique across your table. Each row has its unique primary key.

A foreign key is a field or set of fields, containing only values that are another's table primary key. It is basically a reference to another table.

You can link tables that have references to each others using joins. Here, you are trying to link the Message, Chat and UserChat tables, like so:

```
select 
    *
from
    UserChat
    join
    Chat on UserChat.ChatID = Chat.ChatID
    join
    Message on Chat.ChatID = Message.ChatID
```

As you can see, I "chained" the joins as the relationships are in the diagram.

Now we got our tables linked, we can add our filters, and only select the `Message` fields:

```
select 
    Message.*
from
    UserChat
    join
    Chat on UserChat.ChatID = Chat.ChatID
    join
    Message on Chat.ChatID = Message.ChatID
where
    UserChat.ChatID = y -- Filter the correct chat
    and
    UserChat.MessageID = x -- Filter the correct user
    and
    UserChat.LastOpened < Message.DateSent -- Filter only unread messages
```